# Problems with moving Xcode Project

Tags: xcode4, localization, project-folder

I'm having trouble while moving a Xcode project.
Since I localized the info.plist and main.xib I can't move the project into another location on my mac.

When I move the project, the files get red and building fails.

I set the path of the enclosing man.xib (not the localized) to relative to project but I can't set the location of the localized files.

When the project is moved, the path of the enclosing main.xib is right. But the paths of the localized files remain the same.
I could choose the location of the enclosing file, but since the localized files are stored in de.Iproj and en.Iproj I can't choose a main directory.

Does anybody know this issue or a solution for my problem?
Thanks
Greets
Julian

Answer (score 0):

yes I just got it when I brought my project home.

bad fix for it here

[Localized file paths hard coded in XCode 4 - disappear when project moved to new folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138338/localized-file-paths-hard-coded-in-xcode-4-disappear-when-project-moved-to-new)